# Lato font not separating letters ft and ti

Tags: fonts, fontspec, viewers, kerning, ligatures

I am using the Lato font for a document, but whenever the letters "ft" and "ti" are next to eachother, this font cannot separate the characters. When doing a copy-paste of the word in the output pdf-viewer, weird things happen as "ti" is considered as one letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lato}

\begin{document}
Simulations \huge{\textbf{Institute, simulations}}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: One can see that the ti are glued together]

This should not be the usual output. As one can try on the website
https://fonts2u.com/lato-regular.font?ptext=Simulations the output should look like this (space separation between "t" and "i")
[image: One can see that the ti are separated]

Comment: They're not common ligatures, but it sounds like they are ligatures - [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=disable+%5Bligatures%5D) are a lot of Q&As on disabling them, depending on which engine you're using

Comment: They are part of the `liga` (Standard Ligatures) feature, so they should be enabled by default in most applications using the font. The website you link probably would show them too, but it uses a much older version of the font which probably didn't have them yet: TeX Live has version 2.015 from 2015-08-06, while the website uses 1.010 from 2010-12-12.

Comment: In any case, copy-paste should work correctly for these ligatures. It it doesn't, then there is probably some other issue. But your document works fine with c&p on my system, so it's unclear why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ah they are called ligatures ! 
Thanks @ChrisH this solved my problem, 
`\setmainfont{Lato}[Ligatures=NoCommon]`

Comment: You can block a ligature for a single instance with zero-width hspace or an empty mbox: `Inst\hspace{0pt}itute Inst\mbox{}itute`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the Lato TrueType font has peculiar ligatures, besides the really standard ones, in the `liga` (Standard Ligatures) feature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lato}

\begin{document}

Institute, simulations

flagstaff finicky official

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, this is what I get from copy-pasting here the text from the PDF file:

```
Institute, simulations
flagstaff finicky official
```

so the strange ligatures are split in the process.

You can disable the ligatures, but you can only disable *all* of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lato}[
 Ligatures=NoCommon,
]

\begin{document}

Institute, simulations

flagstaff finicky official

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, this is even better: the glyph shapes don't really need ligatures.

Comment: Font features can be restricted locally to a brace group: `{\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=NoCommon}Institute}` disables *all* ligatures for the word - so its usefulness will depend on the specific word. Otherwise, the `\mbox{}` trick could be used for a specific pairing.

Comment: Off-the-wall question: Since this font is so picky as to have a "ti" ligature, does it have an "fj" ligature?  (There are fjords in some English-speaking countries too.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, from its `liga` feature, `sub \f \j  by \f_j.liga;`

Comment: Thanks.  More fonts should do this.

Answer (score 1):

This font family behaves in surprising ways. One *should* be able to turn off the ligatures you dislike in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "noft",
    type = "multiple",
    data = {
      ['f_f_t.liga'] = { "f", "f", "t" },
      ['f_t.liga'] = { "f", "t" },
      ['t_t_i.liga'] = { "t", "t", "i" },
      ['t_i.liga'] = { "t", "i" },
    },
  }
}
\setsansfont{Lato}[RawFeature=+noft]
\begin{document}
\sffamily
Institute attic simulations pfft baffle five flying officials
\end{document}
```

However, the output is full of the t-ligatures.

If you want the standard ligatures without the others, turn off `liga` and add back the desired ligatures as `rlig` (which is on by default):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "rlig",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['ﬃ'] = { "f", "f", "i" },
      ['ﬄ'] = { "f", "f", "l" },
      ['ﬀ'] = { "f", "f" },
      ['ﬁ'] = { "f", "i" },
      ['ﬂ'] = { "f", "l" },
    },
  }
}
\setsansfont{Lato}[Ligatures=NoCommon]
\begin{document}
\sffamily
Institute attic simulations pfft baffle five flying officials
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I can think of no reason why this second approach works but not the first. The solution requires compiling with `lualatex`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Simulations \huge{\textbf{Institute, simulations}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution would appear to employ pdfLaTeX for compilation, whereas the OP's use of the `fontspec` package clearly indicates that either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX ought to be used.